# Install Mountain Lion now that Mavericks has been released

Tags: macos, upgrade

I foolishly installed Mavericks upon release and my Mac doesn't like it, so I used Internet recovery to downgrade to Lion. I am trying to get back to Mountain Lion but it does not seem possible anymore.

I know I could buy it again from [here](http://store.apple.com/us/product/D6377Z/A/os-x-mountain-lion), but I don't want to pay for it again. I have checked the Purchases tab in the AppStore but it only lists Mavericks.

The only option I have left that I can think of is just torrenting it. This question may look like a duplicate. However, many of the questions are similar, and don't seem to address this issue.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What OS shipped with your Mac? Please edit that into your question or some other details that explain what error happens or why this isn't the same as the other questions that explain how to re-download Mountain Lion.

Comment: It came shipped with Lion, I didn't think I needed to explicitly state that sorry. There is no "error" per say but I am either stuck on Lion or Macericks because I have no way of redownloading it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you bought Mountain Lion but now it has disappeared.

You can unhide purchases (some get hidden or you hid them, does not matter really) by opening Mac App Store.

Then go to: Store->View My Account->Enter AppleID and Password

There should be a "Manage"-Button for Hidden Purchases

[image: manage button for hidden purchases]

Find OS X Mountain Lion and click "Unhide"

Afterwards Mountain Lion should show up in your Purchases Tab and you can reinstall.

Comment: My problem seems to be a whole bother kettle if fish but this answer will probably help people.