# Where can I get a copy of Mavericks after Yosimite has been released?

Tags: snow-leopard, macos

I think I would like to install Mavericks over Snow Leopard on my Intel Core 2 Duo MacBook Pro because I imagine it is more stable than Yosimite and I'm doing a lot of development on it, for which I want Port Tree (Fink in my case) packages to be available for items like Python, PostgreSQL, etc.

But Mavericks doesn't seem to be available on the App store anymore. Tried downloading from CNET, but all I seemed to be finding was an update.

I am tempted to just install Yosemite and would love to get some input.

Comment: Also relevant are these threads: [this one](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/111769) and [that one](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151906)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is buying a bootable 8gig flash drive of it for $20 on Ebay. Just don't have enough peops locally nor expect to count on getting the value out of the balance on the $99 apple dev package - although that's on my radar now.

Comment: Glad you got someone to send it. I'll hope to get a much more general answer that people can edit / confirm as Apple helps them get the previous versions without needing a developer account...

Answer (score 6):

Apple sells redeemable codes for all OS older than current release up to and including Lion from http://store.apple.com

Since the SKU change from time to time, you may need to talk or chat with a sales specialist online to get the correct item into your cart.

I've never had problems just reinstalling the original OS that came with your Mac and then using the App Store to upgrade to a now down-level version of OS X. Also, one you've "purchased" the free or paid upgrades, you can always re-download them from older clients in the purchased section.

Basically, the old OS even going back to 10.6 and earlier are all available for purchase and re-download by either contacting AppleCare or the Apple online / retail stores in your country.

Comment: i had purchased mountain lion so could re-download that. chatting with someone at apple store now. so far they have said "I'm sorry we currently don't have Mavericks available." but I'm pressing the issue...

Comment: "We currently co have them up to LIon, correct." "Even Mountain Lion". Eventually? "So far Apple hasn't announced Mavericks would be available again, so I'm sorry we really don't know about that." Mountain Lion offered at: http://store.apple.com/us/cart/shared_cart/59a9d058-0ac0-4e08-95c1-b9b03cc2aba5

Comment: @MikeiLL If you have a specific Mac you want to get Mavericks, contact AppleCare and ask for an exemption if they want you to pay since you're looking to restore the OS. If you're on store.apple.com chat maybe spend 15 minutes and then thank them for looking. Try again in 30 minutes :-)

Comment: Would that be to see if someone else can provide a link to download the OS?

Comment: At the time of writing, in the Apple Store (UK): [OS X Lion (10.7)](http://store.apple.com/uk/product/D6106ZM/A/os-x-lion) is £14.

Answer (score 4):

You can still get a copy of Mavericks if you are enrolled in the [Apple Developer Mac program](https://developer.apple.com/).  They have a download link to Mavericks available.  It is a cost but your getting genuine downloads from Apple and not 3rd party links.

Comment: Hmmm. $99. Does it seem premature to simply jump into Yosemite?

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer that does not recommend piracy.

Comment: You don't need a [developer license to get old downloads](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/153446/5472).

Comment: @bmike searching for mavericks or 10.9 is still forwarding to the Yosemite page. About how long until they put up the previous version?

Comment: @dwightk My understand is it's up on store.apple.com as a redeemable gift code only. You'll now have to get the download from past purchases or a redeemable code.

Comment: @tron_jones - I'm part of the developer program, but I can't find the download. Can you provide more information?

Comment: @jww https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/index.action  scroll down to redeem a download code

Comment: The developer.apple.com page no longer offers old versions. Only current (Yosemite) and beta (El Capitan) are listed for download.

Answer (score 1):

If you can find someone who "purchased" (it was free) Mavericks in the App Store while it was available, they can still re-download the Mavericks installer and then copy it to your machine.

Comment: Right, anyone that's downloaded it previously would see this under the "Purchases" tab in the App Store.  This would be the best way to get the release.

Comment: Please do not recommend software piracy on Ask Different. The fact that it was free does not change the fact that sharing the software is explicitly against the license agreement.

Comment: This isn't really necessary since anyone that is eligible for a specific old release can almost always download it for free or minimal cost if it involves shipping physical media like Snow Leopard and older... [See my answer on this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/153446/5472)

Comment: @tubedogg - Ask's mission does not include enforcing third party agreements. See [Should moderators enforce NDAs for software vendors?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94465/173448) on Meta.

Comment: @jww Opposing encouraging one to violate federal copyright law is not "enforcing [a] third party agreement". Note the explicit prohibition against discussing piracy in [What topics can I ask about here?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). An NDA is a contract between parties and is irrelevant to this discussion.

Comment: @tubedogg - also remember that there are more legal jurisdictions than the US. While it could be an infringement of some US law, it may be perfectly acceptable in another legal jurisdiction. (And I don't know if its illegal in the US, but I'm side stepping that issue :).

Comment: @jww In terms of unauthorized copying, copyright law is fairly universal thanks to the Berne convention. By your logic, the prohibition I linked to above is meaningless. In any event, it is most assuredly illegal in both the US (where the questioner resides) and the UK (where the poster of this particular answer resides).