# Upgrade vom 10.8 to 10.9

Tags: macos, upgrade

all of my Macs are running OSX Mavericks right now, except one iMac that is still on OSX 10.8.5
I've tried to find a possibility to upgrade to Mavericks, but can only find Yosemite upgrades in the appStore - is there another possibility up upgrade that machine?

Thanks for your hints and ansers,

Thomas

Answer (score 2):

Update: I just found out from this answer [Where can I get a copy of Mavericks after Yosimite has been released?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152506/where-can-i-get-a-copy-of-mavericks-after-yosimite-has-been-released/152512#152512) that it is possible to download if you are a member of the [Apple Developer Mac program](https://developer.apple.com/).

I tried the link from the US Store https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id675248567?mt=12 but it appears it is not available anymore.

I found this from reddit http://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/1oey0b/download_os_x_109_mavericks_gm_final_dmg/

This is the link http://www.techglobex.net/2013/10/download-os-x-109-mavericks-gm-final.html

> Download OS X 10.9 Mavericks GM Final .DMG Setup File (Build: 13A603,
>   Latest, V2) - [Direct Link](http://www.datafile.com/d/TVRJeE5Ua3lNQT0F9) | [Link 2](http://www.datafile.com/d/TVRJd09EQTNNZz0F9) | [Link 3](http://www.datafile.com/d/TVRFMU1EZzJOZz0F9) | [Link 4](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/os-x-mavericks/id675248567?mt=12) | [Torrent Link](http://thepiratebay.se/torrent/9104190/Mac_OS_X_10.9_Mavericks_Install_DVD_Retail) |[Link 2](http://thepiratebay.se/torrent/9012642/OS_X_Mavericks_10.9_Retail_VMware_Image)
>
> Download OS X 10.9 Mavericks Server GM Final .DMG Setup File
>
> Download Xcode 5.0.1 GM (Build: 5A2034a) Download iPhoto 9.4.7 Seed
>
> Download Remote Desktop (Build: 370A61) Download .DMG Extractor for
>   .IPSW Files - [Direct Link](http://www.reincubate.com/res/labs/dmge/dmge-latest.exe)

Make sure you check if it is legitimate https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202369

> For OS X Lion or later, locate the lock icon () in the upper-right
>   corner of the Installer window’s title bar.
>
> For Mac OS X Snow Leopard, a certificate icon is shown instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you have ever previously 'bought' Mavericks from the App Store, it will be available in your Purchases list & you can download it again.

Mine is showing 'resume' as I tried a partial download to test it still works.

[image]