# Abort OS X download initiated through App Store?

Tags: macos

I started an OS X Yosemite download. I did not want to download it or install it; rather I just wanted it to show up under purchases so I could install it in the future after Apple removes it from the App Store. It will avoid problems like [Where can I get a copy of Mavericks after Yosemite has been released?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/152506)

The *Pause* button is not available (its greyed out), so I can't pause or stop the download.

How do I abort the download now that the "purchase" has been made?

---

[image]

Comment: why not download it but not install, then you are sure to have it. if a space is a issue, you get free google drive 10 Gig where you can keep it.

Comment: It's "waiting" which means something else is currently downloading, and it will start after that's done. Once it starts, the Pause button will be enabled. I don't believe there's a way to stop the download entirely, though.

Answer (score 2):

You could just go to the Applications folder on your Mac, and find the App that is downloading, and delete it from there.  Once you do this, it should pop up a box asking you if you want to cancel the download.  Just select yes and cancel it.

I've done this before and it worked fine.  Usually, I just let it fully download, then uninstall/remove the App with an App called Clean My Mac, or App Zapper.  Both are great apps for uninstalling/removing Apps and other stuff from you Mac completely/fully.

Hope this helps :)

-James